# Proving associativity and commutativity of a matrix product multiplied by a scalar

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I want to prove that c(AB) = (cA)B = A(cB), where A and B are matrices (with defined products) and c is a scalar.

$$c\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{ik}b_{kj} = \sum_{k=1}^{n}ca_{ik}\cdot\sum_{k=1}^{n}b_{kj} = \sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{ik}\cdot\sum_{k=1}^{n}cb_{kj}$$

Here, k represents the current column of A and row of B while summing the products of the entries. This is supposed to show that when computing an entry of the new matrix AB, multiplying the sum of the entry products by a scalar is no different than multiplying $a_{ik}$ by a scalar before taking each product with $b_{kj}$, and so on. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof is fine, but it's worth contextualizing what it does. The result is the special case with $M=cI$ of $A,\,B,\,M$ associating, since multiples of $I$ commute with everything viz. $cIX=cX=cXI=XcI$. Your technique also easily proves the more general fact that matrices associate, viz.$$((AB)M)_{ij}=\sum_l(AB)_{il}M_{lj}=\sum_{kl}A_{ik}B_{kl}M_{lj}=\sum_kA_{ik}(BM)_{kj}=(A(BM))_{ij}.$$(Also, this can all be [made more concise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation).)